# How can I generate a PNG from an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching a way to generate a png from an svg file without using document, window or canvas because i'm working without browser and without DOM.

The results that I have found used `document.getElementById` or `window` ...

Is it possible to do this without DOM implementation?

Comment: What exactly are you using if not a browser?

Comment: @Juhana i don't execute my js code in html file, so i don't have all browser   functionalities, i have to use basic javascript functions, jquerynodom ...

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm working with javascript client not server side

Comment: @Caroline How are you running JS w/o a browser or Node? Without any details it's a lot harder to help.

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm runnig my js using abap